# Python script object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

```
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture
from app import main
from app import quicksight_utils
from app import serializer_utils



def data source(aws_account_id: str, ds: str) -> None:
    return {
      "aws account id": aws account_id,
      "data source": ds

      }

def test export_data_sources (mocker: MockerFixture) -> None:
    mocker.patch("app.quicksight_utils.get_data_source_by_name", side effect=data_source)
    mocker.patch("app.serializer_utils.save_object")

    main.export_data_sources()

    calls = [mocker.call(main. AWS ACCOUNT_ID, ds) for ds in main.DATA_SOURCES]
    quicksight_utils.get_data_source_by_name.assert_has_calls (calls)
    calls = [mocker.call({ "aws account_id": main. AWS_ACCOUNT_ID, "data_source": ds }, f"{ds).pkl") for ds in main.DATA_SOURCES]
    serializer_utils.save_object.has_calls(calls)
```

Error when running the python script manually. Can fix it by removing the indexing call or defining the **getitem** method. But new to python need to know how and why to fix it.

Comment: nothing is subscripted in the script you display? can you give a stack trace of the error?

Comment: getting error as 'type' object is not subscriptable